# How to undersample/oversample more than two classes' dataset using "imblearn" library in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, imbalanced-data, imblearn

I am working with "imblearn" library for undersampling. I have four classes in my dataset each having 20, 30, 40 and 50 number of data(as it is an imbalanced class).

But when I try to undersample the dataset using "fit_resample(X, y)", it only undersamples the first and last classes.

Is there any way I can undersample all the four classes using "imblearn"?

Necessary code:

```
undersample = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')
X_over, y_over = undersample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved setting **smapling_strategy='all'**.